# How to destroy a Node.js http.request connection nicely?

Tags: http, node.js, request, destroy

If I run it in the command line, the program will stop after client.destroy();

```
var client = http.get(options, 
        function(res) {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            client.destroy();
          }
);
```

However, it is not the case when I put the client.destroy() inside the res.on('end'):

```
var client = http.get(options, 
        function(res) {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            res.on('end', function() {
                console.log("done");
                client.destroy();
            });
          }
);
```

It will throw exception because the http.socket is null.  so, I can't destroy it.

IN this case, the program execution will hang there and will not end.  What can I do to stop it? (other than process.exit());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if it's single request you can just set shouldKeepAlive to false

```
var request = http.get(options, 
        function(res) {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
          }
);
request.shouldKeepAlive = false
```

or send `Connection: close` header

You can't access socket because it is [detached](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L346) in [the request 'end' event handler](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1328)

Comment: when I do 'request.shouldKeepAlive" , does it affect anything on the socket pooling?

Comment: it probably better to use Connection header, it is analysed here - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L442 This affects request shouldKeepAlive flag

Comment: Guys, stop linking line numbers in "master" -- it's useless -- you can't link a line number on a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

Call `res.req.destroy()`.

See: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestdestroyerror

Answer (score 0):

**To your question**:
request created by http.get or http.request will close its socket(connection) by default. You don't have to close it.

**To your code example**:
Nodejs has registered res.on('end', responseOnEnd) before your "res.on('end', yourCb)".
responseOnEnd will close the socket. Because responseOnEnd is called before yourCb,so you can't destory the socket in res.on('end', yourCb) .